# System.InvalidOperationException when trying to save in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with Entity Framework using a Oracle database. What I'm trying to do is to save a new Entity using a old entity as base. I take all the properties of the old entity and take them to a new one, this with the objective of avoid problems with duplication of entities or multiple references.

I'm doing something like this:

```
List < PPL_FAMILIAR_RESPONSABLE > familiares = new List < PPL_FAMILIAR_RESPONSABLE > ();
foreach(PPL_FAMILIAR_RESPONSABLE fr in registro.PPL_FAMILIAR_RESPONSABLE) {
 familiares.Add(new PPL_FAMILIAR_RESPONSABLE {
  FR_NOMBRE = fr.FR_NOMBRE,
   FR_APPATERNO = fr.FR_APPATERNO,
   FR_APMATERNO = fr.FR_APMATERNO,
   PARENTESCO = fr.PARENTESCO,
   COLONIA = fr.COLONIA,
   CALLE = fr.CALLE,
   FR_SEXO = fr.FR_SEXO,
   NUMERO_EXT = fr.NUMERO_EXT,
   NUMERO_INT = fr.NUMERO_INT
 });
}
List < PPL_ALIAS > alias = new List < PPL_ALIAS > ();
foreach(PPL_ALIAS a in registro.PPL_ALIAS) {
 alias.Add(new PPL_ALIAS {
  NOMBRE_ALIAS = a.NOMBRE_ALIAS,
   APPATERNO_ALIAS = a.APPATERNO_ALIAS,
   APMATERNO_ALIAS = a.APMATERNO_ALIAS
 });
}
List < PPL_APODO > apodos = new List < PPL_APODO > ();
foreach(PPL_APODO a in registro.PPL_APODO) {
 apodos.Add(new PPL_APODO {
  APODO = a.APODO,
 });
}
List < PPL_PANDILLA > pandillas = new List < PPL_PANDILLA > ();
foreach(PPL_PANDILLA p in registro.PPL_PANDILLA) {
 pandillas.Add(new PPL_PANDILLA {
  NOTAS = p.NOTAS,
   CAT_PANDILLA = p.CAT_PANDILLA,
 });
}

List < PPL_RELACIONES_PERSONALES > relaciones = new List < PPL_RELACIONES_PERSONALES > ();
foreach(PPL_RELACIONES_PERSONALES rp in registro.PPL_RELACIONES_PERSONALES) {
 relaciones.Add(new PPL_RELACIONES_PERSONALES {
  RP_NOMBRE = rp.RP_NOMBRE,
   RP_APMATERNO = rp.RP_APMATERNO,
   RP_APPATERNO = rp.RP_APPATERNO,
   PARENTESCO = rp.PARENTESCO,
   NOTAS = rp.NOTAS
 });
}
List < PPL_PERTENENCIAS > pertenencias = new List < PPL_PERTENENCIAS > ();
foreach(PPL_PERTENENCIAS p in registro.PPL_PERTENENCIAS) {
 pertenencias.Add(new PPL_PERTENENCIAS {
  PERTENENCIA = p.PERTENENCIA,
   DESCRIPCION = p.DESCRIPCION
 });
}
PPL_REGISTRO r = new PPL_REGISTRO {
 AUTORIDAD_DISPOSICION = registro.AUTORIDAD_DISPOSICION,
  AUTORIDAD_INTERNADO = registro.AUTORIDAD_INTERNADO,
  CLASIFICACION = registro.CLASIFICACION,
  EDIFICIO = registro.EDIFICIO,
  ESTATUS_ADMINISTRATIVOS = registro.ESTATUS_ADMINISTRATIVOS,
  FECHA_INGRESO = registro.FECHA_INGRESO,
  FECHA_REGISTRO = registro.FECHA_REGISTRO,
  NUM_OFICIO = registro.NUM_OFICIO,
  TIPO_INGRESO = registro.TIPO_INGRESO,
  TIPO_SEGURIDAD = registro.TIPO_SEGURIDAD,
  UBICACION = registro.UBICACION,
  DELITO = registro.DELITO,
  PPL_DATOS_GENERALES = registro.PPL_DATOS_GENERALES,
  PPL_PERTENENCIAS = pertenencias,
  PPL_ALIAS = alias,
  PPL_APODO = apodos,
  PPL_FAMILIAR_RESPONSABLE = familiares,
  PPL_RELACIONES_PERSONALES = relaciones,
  PPL_MEDIA_FILIACION = registro.PPL_MEDIA_FILIACION,
  PPL_PANDILLA = pandillas
};
using(var bl = new BLRegistroPPL()) {
 bl.CrearRegistroPPL(r);
}
```

As you can see I use the entity `registro` as base to create a new `PPL_REGISTRO` entity. I take all the values of registro and pass them to a new Entity, and with the relationships I iterate over them and create a new list with complete new objects, and assign them to the new PPL_REGISTRO entity I'm creating.
After that I want to save the new entity in the database using the `CrearRegistroPPL` method to save it:

```
public void CrearRegistroPPL(PPL_REGISTRO registroPPL) {
 context.PPL_REGISTRO.Add(registroPPL);
 context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But at the moment of save it, the app throw me the next error:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'`
What this can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted should not be the problem.

> multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

points to another problem.

Most probably there is another active entity framework db context and some entity is tracked by both of them.

Comment: Is there a way to check what context are active?

Comment: None I know of. I guess you need to review our source code and/or set a breakpoint everywhere you create a context.